# Why hasn't this question been closed?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, close-reasons

I came across [this question](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/q/2580/2856) and wondered why it hasn't been closed. It seems to be both opinion based and too broad (two questions in the post). 
As a moderator in [GIS.SE](http://gis.stackexchange.com), I would not hesitate to close this question, even with the high number of up votes.

I understand that this site is still in beta and wondered if that is why it remains open. I think it's a good idea at this stage of a site to keep questions open until the site graduates from beta. Once that happens I think the past should be closed until it is narrowed down.

I do feel that people need to get into the habit of not posting opinion based questions and limiting to one question per post. Perhaps we need to educate people on how the site works.

It's this the general consensus?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like one of our early self-answered questions which was created to help seed the site with useful content.

I see what you mean about it seeming like an opinion question at first glance, although upon closer reading you will see the crux of the question is this part, which the answers did address objectively:

> As far as woodworking is concerned what would make one preferential
>   over the other or is this just a matter of personal preference?

There certainly is an opportunity here to edit out any parts that make it seem like an opinion-based question, but I personally appreciate the humor in the title and graphic.